# Way to make all subsequent drawing calls apply to a specific drawing context in Processing

Tags: java, drawing, processing

I have a lot of drawing calls in my code (`beginShape()`, `vertex()`, `line()`, fills, strokes, and more). At the moment they apply to the global drawing context. Is there a way to switch the drawing context without having to go through the code and change all the drawing calls?

For instance:

```
line(0, 0, 0, 40);
moreDrawingCode();
```

Turns into:

```
useContext(pg); // pg is a PGraphics object for instance
line(0, 0, 0, 40);
moreDrawingCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this code:

```
void draw() {
  drawStuff();
}

void drawStuff(){
   ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);  
}
```

If you want to be able to change this code to draw to a different `PGraphics`, you're going to have to modify your code to take a `PGraphics` as a parameter:

```
void drawStuff(PGraphics graphics){
   graphics.ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);  
}
```

If you want to draw to the screen, just use the predefined `g` variable:

```
drawStuff(g);
```

Or you can pass in a PGraphics that you create. Don't forget to call `beginDraw()` and `endDraw()`:

```
  pg.beginDraw();
  drawStuff(pg);
  pg.endDraw();
```

Putting it all together, it might look something like this:

```
PGraphics pg;

void setup() {
  size(200, 100);
  pg = createGraphics(100, 100);
}

void drawStuff(PGraphics graphics){
   graphics.ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);  
}

void draw() {
  drawStuff(g);

  pg.beginDraw();
  drawStuff(pg);
  pg.endDraw();

  image(pg, 100, 0);
}
```

You could also store the `PGraphics` to draw to in a sketch-level variable instead of passing it in as a parameter, but that feels messier to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can create just static context variable, and you'll get something like that:

```
class MyClass {
    private static Context context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Context contextA = new Context();
        Context contextB = new Context();

        useContext(contextA);
        line(0, 0, 5, 5);

        useContext(contextB);
        line(0, 0, 5, 5);

    }

    public static void useContext(Context newContext) {
        context = newContext;
    }

    public static void line(int x, int y, int x2, int y2) {
        drawInContext(context, x, y, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question. While Processing shares some syntax with Java, [Processing != Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java), so Java answers aren't always the best fit for Processing questions.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, Why author tagged this question with 'Java' tag?

Comment: Please see [this thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) for a discussion on that question.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, Okay. It's cool. But it's wrong and confusing. Processing sounds like 'processing of something...'. And when you tagged question about "Processing" with 'Java' tag.. it's wrong. It's really confusing. I think better name for this language, processing-lang or something like that.

Comment: I didn't name the language or the tag. If you think it should be renamed, please take it to meta.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, I mean, this question has Java tag. It's one reason, why I'm here. And I'm confusing, that first tag of question is 'Java', but question not about Java.

Comment: I understand, but I didn't choose any of these tags, or any of their names. I understand your confusion, which is why I posted that meta discussion. But I can't really do anything about it. I invite you to start your own meta discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115530/discussion-between-ivan-and-kevin-workman).